# How to make a looped ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make a looped `ListView`, such that after the end of the show will be the initial object.
Can anyone give a reference to the decision or bring it should look something like this menu with [pictures](http://hsto.org/files/8f9/2b1/5ad/8f92b15ade60469a9bfb825837ae4778.png) only fixated.

Comment: Adapt getCount in the adapter. Let it return for instance 1000 where you only have 100 items in a list. Then in getView convert position to listposition with `int listposition=position%10; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create own adapter using i.e. `BaseAdapter` and inside

```
public class OwnAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<Object> objects; //init by your own

    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position % object.size());
    }

    // and other abstract methods like getView etc.
}
```