# How to make an endless ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make an endless ListView, if my program is used vertical listView, I used this [site](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) for additions that would not write knit , but have not quite figured out how to use it. So I need to do listView obsessed , do not quite understand how it can be implemented.
Here chat code where it is created :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ..
   HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3","Text #3","Text #3" };

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {
    ArrayList<Object> objects;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return dataObjects.length;//
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_leyout, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: What isn't working? It isn't endless because you don't have an endless list... You have an array of 5 Strings.

Comment: tip: if your adapter returns `x` in `getCount()` then your list view will show `x` items, so if you want your list view to be endless it should show infinite number of items, of course **int** variable cannot represent infinity so return the maximum value that is possible here

Comment: @poskink, I understand that , just as I constitute your number in my program crashes , for example have a number of INT 10. There is a collapse of the application.

Comment: @zgc7009, I tried to do all of this [example][1] , but the application crashes .[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192156/how-to-make-a-looped-listview

Comment: Ohhh you are just trying to loop it, change your count number and use modulus to loop.

Comment: Do you want to have an "endless" ListView, or do you want a revolving ListView? I mean, do you want the items to display higher and higher numbers in your "Text #1", or does it display the same five items again and again? You cannot specify an endless List, so if you want the ListView to be really endless, can't base it on a List, you have to make up the items on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHange getCount to return a huge number

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;//
}
```

and of course

```
title.setText(dataObjects[position]);
```

should be something like

```
title.setText(dataObjects[position%dataObjects.lenght]);
```

Comment: crashes when trying to do something like that

Comment: @emigrantdd define "crash". What is happening? Post a crash log in an update in your post.

Comment: @zgc7009, but no, the country earned , although how many times did the same thing , well it does not matter much for the answer )